# Manipulating multiproperty AD attributes (ProxyAddresses)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of users with several values in their `ProxyAddresses` attribute e.g.

```
SMTP:JohnSmith@domain1.com
smtp:jsmith@domain2.com
smtp:ukCC10s@domain2.com
smtp:smith.john@domain3.com
```

and many other unknown ones.

What I want to do is:

1. Convert all existing addresses that begin with smtp/SMTP to lowercase
2. Add/replace the one that conforms to the **SMTP:firstname.surname@Domain2.com** standard (to make it the primary)

I've not got very far, running this just strips all proxyaddresses out and adds the one specified:

```
$userou = "OU=test2,OU=Test,OU=Users,DC=Corp,DC=Local"
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $userou -Properties SamAccountName, ProxyAddresses

foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{'ProxyAddresses'="SMTP:blah@blah.com"}
}
```

How do I enumerate through each value in a multivalue attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should do what you need.
It updates the ProxyAddresses multivalue property so that all 'smtp/SMTP' addresses will become lowercase and the new Primary emailaddress is computed and inserted in the list.

I have added a small helper function to replace diacritic characters that may appear in the users first or last name because especially Outlook 365 does not handle these characters very well.

```
$userou = "OU=test2,OU=Test,OU=Users,DC=Corp,DC=Local"
$users  = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $userou -Properties SamAccountName, ProxyAddresses, EmailAddress


function Replace-Diacritics {
    # helper function to replace characters in email addresses that especially Outlook365 does not like..
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string] $EmailAdress
    )
    $chars = @()
    $normalized = $EmailAdress.Normalize( [Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD )
    $normalized.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object { 
        if( [Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($_) -ne [Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark) {
            $chars += $_
        }
    }
    $chars -join ''
}

foreach ($user in $users) {
    # create the new primary emailaddress
    # remove invalid characters and replace diacritics ("Frédérique.Étrangér@Domain2.com" --> "frederique.etranger@domain2.com")
    $newPrimary = ($("{0}.{1}@Domain2.com" -f $user.GivenName, $user.Surname) -replace '[\s()<>,;:''"{}/[\]\\]+', '').ToLower()
    $newPrimary = "SMTP:" + (Replace-Diacritics ($newPrimary -replace '\.+', '.'))

    # get all email addresses and convert them to lowercase. At the same time dedupe this array.
    # this will also replace 'SMTP:' of the former Primary email address to become an alias ('smtp:')
    $emailAliases = @($user.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -match '^smtp:.*' -and $_ -ne $newPrimary } | 
                                             ForEach-Object { $_.ToLower() } |
                                             Sort-Object -Unique)
    # read all other existing stuff
    $otherAddresses = @($user.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^smtp:.*' })

    # now merge all addresses into one array, the Primary email address on top for easier reading in ADUC
    $newProxies = (@($newPrimary) + $emailAliases) + $otherAddresses

    # finally replace the users ProxyAddresses property. I like:
    $user | Set-ADUser -Clear ProxyAddresses
    $user | Set-ADUser -Add @{'proxyAddresses'=$newProxies }
    # but you could also do
    # $user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{'proxyAddresses' = $newProxies}

    # finally, put the new primary email address in the users 'mail' property
    $user | Set-ADUser -EmailAddress $($newPrimary -replace 'SMTP:', '')
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try!

Comment: @Aziz Please see the edited code. The previous code had an error that *could* mean losing the former primary email address. The new code transforms this old primary address into an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, because I don't have an AD at my disposal here, but I'd expect something like this to work, since multivalued attributes should be returned as collections.

```
$addr = $user.ProxyAddresses -creplace '^SMTP:', 'smtp:'
$addr += 'SMTP:blah@blah.com'
$user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{ 'ProxyAddresses' = $addr }
```

To assign the correct new primary address to each user you could map the addresses to usernames in a hashtable and then do a lookup rather than assign the new primary address as a static value:

```
$addr += $newPrimaryAddress[$user.SamAccountName]
```